# Oracle REST API dictionaries

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql

Do we have any alternatives of ALL_ORDS_MODULES or DBA_ORDS_MODULES. We can only select USER_ORDS_MODULES from the current user. However my requirement is slightly different. My package is in different schema than where ORDS mudules/templates/handlers are configured and the package needs to access some data (like paginations etc.) from the ORDS modules.

Comment: Until we have a solution, what I am ultimately doing - have created a table for each USER_ORDS_XXXX dictionaries and these tables will refreshed daily by a scheduled job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no `ALL_ORDS_MODULES' oder`DBA_ORDS_MODULES`. You can check with

```
SELECT object_type, owner, object_name
  FROM dba_objects 
 WHERE object_name LIKE '%ORDS_MODULES';

OBJECT_TYPE OWNER          OBJECT_NAME
VIEW        ORDS_METADATA  USER_ORDS_MODULES
TABLE       ORDS_METADATA  ORDS_MODULES
SYNONYM     PUBLIC         USER_ORDS_MODULES
```

With `ALL_ORDS_MODULES` being a view, you could have a look at it's definition and build a query based on it. The Apex views change quite a bit from release to release, so that's not only unsupported, of course, but probably also only a short lived solution.

```
SELECT text FROM dba_views WHERE view_name='USER_ORDS_MODULES';
```

Comment: Thank you. Instead of view I can directly access ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_MODULES table

Comment: Good! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers